# How to make one mySQL's table column invisible

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtable, tablemodel

I am running a query on ID column but I don't want it to be visible in my frame/pane. How can I achieve this? Shall I make another table, is there a function in sql/mysql which allows to hide columns? I tried to google it but havent found anything yet.
Here is the code:

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int col = e.getColumn();
    model = (MyTableModel) e.getSource();
    String stulpPav = model.getColumnName(col);
    Object data = model.getValueAt(row, col);
    Object studId = model.getValueAt(row, 0);
    System.out.println("tableChanded works");
    try {
        new ImportData(stulpPav, data, studId);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public class ImportData {
    Connection connection = TableWithBottomLine.getConnection();

    public ImportData(String a, Object b, Object c)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {

            String stulpPav = a;
            String duom = b.toString();
            String studId = c.toString();
            System.out.println(duom);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.addBatch("update finance.fin set " + stulpPav + " = " + duom
                    + " where ID = " + studId + ";");
            stmt.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            System.out.println("Data was imported to database");
        }
    }   
    }        
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    int rowCount;
    Object data [][];
    String columnNames [];
    public  MyTableModel() throws SQLException{
        String query ="SELECT ID, tbl_Date as Date, Flat, Mobile, Food, Alcohol, Transport, Outdoor, Pauls_stuff, Income, Stuff FROM finance.fin";
        ResultSet rs ;
        Connection connection = TableWithBottomLine.getConnection();

        Statement stmt = null;
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        rs.last();
        rowCount = rs.getRow();
        data = new Object[rowCount][11];
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        for (int iEil = 0; iEil < rowCount; iEil++){
            rs.next();
            data[iEil][0] = rs.getInt("ID");
            data[iEil][1] = rs.getDate("Date");
            data[iEil][2] = rs.getFloat("Flat");
            data[iEil][3]  = rs.getFloat("Mobile");
            data[iEil][4] = rs.getFloat("Food");
            data[iEil][5]  = rs.getFloat("Alcohol");
            data[iEil][6] = rs.getFloat("Transport");
            data[iEil][7] = rs.getFloat("Outdoor");
            data[iEil][8] = rs.getFloat("Pauls_stuff");
            data[iEil][9] = rs.getFloat("Income");
            data[iEil][10] = rs.getFloat("Stuff");
        }

         String[] columnName  = {"ID", "Date","Flat","Mobile"        
                ,"Food","Alcohol","Transport", "Outdoor", "Pauls_stuff", "Income", "Stuff"};
         columnNames = columnName;
    }
```

Comment: If you dont want to display the ID column and if it is not needed in your query you can leave it in your select statement and display the remaining results...

Comment: Also, you can leave ID out of your data array and put Date in column 0, Flat in column 1, etc.  And stop trying to steal my name! :)

Comment: ID column is needed in the query but not needed to be visible when showing data. OK, I need to digest info ;) thanks for replies.

Comment: I tried Paul's and Bart's approach but unsuccessfully. Table is shown without ID column BUT data is not changed in the database. This is the part where ID is used in my code: stmt.addBatch("update finance.fin set " + stulpPav + " = " + duom + " where ID = " + studId + ";");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has solved my problem:

```
table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
```

I placed this in my class contructor. This lets remove the column from the view of the table but column 'ID' is still contained in the TableModel. I found that many people looking for an option to exclude specific column (like autoincrement) from SELECT statement in sql / mysql but the language itself doesn't have that feature. So I hope this solution will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put ID in the select part of the query

```
String query ="SELECT tbl_Date as Date, Flat, Mobile, Food, Alcohol, Transport,    
Outdoor, Pauls_stuff, Income, Stuff FROM finance.fin";
```